# how to plot wind average using era5 data?

Tags: python

I tried to make some plot for wind average in one day, I got an error saying that "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable' and 'int".

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
data = Dataset(r'C:/Users/MERRA2_400.inst3_3d_asm_Nv.20200101.nc4', mode='r')
# longitude and latitude
lons = data.variables['lon']
lats = data.variables['lat']
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
# 2-meter eastward wind m/s
U2M = data.variables['U']
# 2-meter northward wind m/s
V2M = data.variables['V']
U2M_nans = U2M[:]
V2M_nans = V2M[:]
_FillValueU2M = U2M._FillValue
_FillValueV2M = V2M._FillValue
U2M_nans[U2M_nans == _FillValueU2M] = np.nan
V2M_nans[V2M_nans == _FillValueV2M] = np.nan
ws = np.sqrt(U2M**2+V2M**2)
ws_daily_avg = np.nanmean(ws, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You raise a netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable to the power of 2, which python doesn't know how to do.

So you need to convert your U2M and V2M to numbers. I cannot tell what you really have there. If it is just a number then convert it. If it is an array-like thingy, then put it into a panda and do the math there.

example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'u': [12.1,12.2,15],'v': [4, 3, 13.1]})
# print(np.power(df['u'], 2))
# print(np.power(df['v'], 2))
# print(np.power(df['u'], 2)+np.power(df['v'], 2))
print(np.power(np.power(df['u'], 2)+np.power(df['v'], 2),0.5))
```